# How the preserve the original multindex header of a dataframe when making a worksheet table with xlsxwriter?

Tags: xlsxwriter

My input is a dataframe and I need to save it in Excel as a table.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['x', 'y', 'z']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, len(columns)*5+1).reshape(-1, len(columns)), index=range(5), columns=columns)

print(df)

    A           B        
    x   y   z   x   y   z
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   7   8   9  10  11  12
2  13  14  15  16  17  18
3  19  20  21  22  23  24
4  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

```
row = df.shape[0]
col = df.shape[1]

with pd.ExcelWriter('final_template.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
    writer.sheets['Sheet1'].add_table(1, 1, row+2, col, {'autofilter': True})
    writer.sheets['Sheet1'].autofit()
```

The code works fine except one thing, the column names are not preserved.

Can you show me guys how to fix that ? I need `['x', 'y', 'z'], ...` instead of `['column1', ...]`.

My actual excel file looks like below :

[image]

I found an article that explain how to do that but the example used is not multindex.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-a-dataframe-to-a-worksheet-table

Comment: What do you want the header to be, given that the Excel table will not allow Headers with the same name? So you cannot have 'x', 'y', 'z' as headers for both column B-D and columns E-G. You can get unique header values from the dataframe header as a combination of the row 1 & 2 header, e.g. 'Ax', 'Ay', 'Az', 'Bx', 'By', 'Bz'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic option to add the combined dataframe header to the table cleaned up so it is unique and doesn't include unwanted characters.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['x', 'y', 'z']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, len(columns) * 5 + 1).reshape(-1, len(columns)), index=range(5), columns=columns)

row = df.shape[0]
col = df.shape[1]


with pd.ExcelWriter('final_template.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
    
    ### Get column headers from dataframe and clean up additional characters
    column_headers = [{'header': re.sub("'|\(|\)|,| ", "", str(c))} for c in df.columns]
    ### Include headers in the table
    writer.sheets['Sheet1'].add_table(1, 1, row + 2, col, {'columns': column_headers, 'autofilter': True})

    writer.sheets['Sheet1'].autofit()
```

[image: Sheet with unique headers]

Comment: Thank you moken. It worked and your proposition is good for me.